# Getting NoMatchingViewException during perform(...), but not the preceding check(...)

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have this simple Espresso interaction:

```
onView(atIndex(withId(R.id.editTextTextWidget), 0)).inRoot(authViewRootMatcher)
                .check(matches(allOf(isDisplayed(), isEnabled())))
                .perform(typeText("1"));
```

The `check(matches(allOf(isDisplayed(), isEnabled())))` passes as expected, but the following `perform(typeText("1"))` does not. I cannot figure out why, for the life of me.

So, I can't believe I'm asking this, but how in the name of Android do I use `Espresso` to type text into my `EditText` whose ID is `R.id.editTextTextWidget`?

Comment: Why `inRoot()`? Is it in `Dialog`?

Comment: @azizbekian the `EditText` is inside a floating `View` that is shown by `WindowManager.addView(...)`. `authViewRootMatcher` matches the expected root correctly.

Comment: Why are you sure `check()` matches exactly the `EditText` you plan it to match? because I see you have multiple of them (atIndex(.., 0)).

Comment: I'm pretty sure, the `atIndex` matcher is to avoid ambiguous views exception. I don't get the `NoMatchingViewException` if I remove the `perform(typeText("1"))` call and only have the `check(matches(allOf(isDisplayed(), isEnabled())))` call. Also, thanks for the quick responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by splitting the `check(...)` call and `perform(...)` call:

```
onView(atIndex(withId(R.id.editTextTextWidget), 0)).inRoot(authViewRootMatcher)
        .check(matches(allOf(isDisplayed(), isEnabled())));
onView(atIndex(withId(R.id.editTextTextWidget), 0)).inRoot(authViewRootMatcher)
        .perform(typeText("1"));
```

For some reason this works, and the original doesn't. #GooglePlz